# Bash - calendário e data atual com "if else"

Tags: if, ubuntu, bash, else

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "1 - calendario"
echo "2 - data"
echo "opção: "
read var

if [$var -eq 1];
 then
         calendario=$(cal)
         echo $calendario
elif [$var -eq 2];
then
        now=$(date)
        echo $now
else
        echo "opção invalida"
fi
```

isto é o output:

```
1 - calendario
2 - data
opção:
1
./calendar.sh: line 8: [1: command not found
./calendar.sh: line 12: [1: command not found
opção invalida
```

Quero dar ao utilizador duas opções, uma para dar print a um calendario e outra à data atual, mas sem usar "case", só com "if else", não sei o que estou a fazer de errado

Comment: a última linha do seu código é `fi` mesmo?
de qualquer forma, tente estruturar/formatar melhor a pergunta, tá um pouco confusa

Comment: já tentei mudar para que se entendesse melhor, mas sim, é ```fi``` mesmo

Answer (score 1):

O erro diz que na *linha 8* (`if [$var -eq 1];`) e na *linha 12* (`elif [$var -eq 2];`) tem *comando inválido*.

O `if` não tem `;` no final do comando, que seria o erro indicado (vide [sintaxe](http://Scanning))

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "1 - calendario"
echo "2 - data"
echo "opção: "
read var

if [$var -eq 1]
then
    calendario=$(cal)
    echo $calendario
elif [$var -eq 2]
then
    now=$(date)
    echo $now
else
    echo "opção invalida"
fi
```